# DQN stuck at suboptimal policy in Atari Pong task

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, dqn, implementation, atari-games

I am in the process of implementing the DQN model from scratch in PyTorch with the target environment of Atari Pong. After a while of tweaking hyper-parameters, I cannot seem to get the model to achieve the performance that is reported in most publications (~ +21 reward; meaning that the agent wins almost every volley).

My most recent results are shown in the following figure. Note that the x axis is episodes (full games to 21), but the total training iterations is ~6.7 million.

[image]

The specifics of my setup are as follows:

#### Model

```
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, outputs):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=32, kernel_size=8, stride=4)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=64*7*7 , out_features=512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=outputs)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 7 * 7)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x    # return Q values of each action
```

#### Hyperparameters

- batch size: 32
- replay memory size: 100000
- initial epsilon: 1.0
- epsilon anneals linearly to 0.02 over 100000 steps
- random warmstart episodes: ~50000
- update target model every: 1000 steps
- optimizer = optim.RMSprop(policy_net.parameters(),  lr=0.0025, alpha=0.9, eps=1e-02, momentum=0.0)

#### Additional info

- OpenAI gym Pong-v0 environment
- Feeding model stacks of 4 last observed frames, scaled and cropped to 84x84 such that only the "playing area" is visible.
- Treat losing a volley (end-of-life) as a terminal state in the replay buffer.
- Using [smooth_l1_loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#smooth-l1-loss), which acts as Huber loss
- Clipping gradients between -1 and 1 before optimizing
- I offset the beginning of each episode with 4-30 no-op steps as the papers suggest

Has anyone had a similar experience of getting stuck around 6 - 9 average reward per episode like this?

Any suggestions for changes to hyperparameters or algorithmic nuances would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Mink , I am working on the same project right now, but my average score is capped at -10. Some differences I can see between our implementations are:

* "PongDeterministic-v4" environment which takes care of frame skipping.
* did not crop the score part on the top, but my frames are 84 x 84.
* do not treat losing a volley as a terminal state.
* replay buffer size is 50000. RAM fills up and overflows if I use any more than that. No idea how you managed to store 100000 experience tuples.
* using l2 loss, was planning to switch to huber loss though.

Do you have a Github repo?

Comment: @hridayns, to prevent memory overflow, I save the images as uint8 type in my replay buffer and cast (and divide by 255) right before I forward pass it to my model.

Comment: By the way, the GitHub repo is https://github.com/MatthewInkawhich/learnRL

Comment: I have done the same uint8 conversion. I was planning to normalize them by 255 too, but I believe they take up the same memory, whether divided or not. I was thinking I might lose information if I did that. What do you think? Also, I have followed you on github. In regards to your issue, I was thinking maybe it has something to do with your target network update frequency. It could be too low, causing instability during learning? Another thing you could try is a Prioritized Replay buffer.

Comment: @hridayns thanks for the suggestions, I will try that. Also, I would recommend always normalizing your image inputs between 0 and 1, as it tends to play nicer with the initial weights and activation function.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably implement that then. Along with better initialization schemes for the networks, gradient and reward clipping. You can check out my repo here if you like: https://github.com/hridayns/Reinforcement-Learning/

Comment: According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363141/3623131), using a squared loss function with gradient clipping is equivalent to using a Huber loss function without the gradient clipping. Gradient clipping step may not be required for you since you are using something close to Huber loss already.

Answer (score 1):

Incase you still haven't been able to resolve the problem, here's a link to the [answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/10481/21513) to my own question, which has the step-wise changes I made to achieve a +18 average score saturation using just a 10000 replay buffer size and a normal Double DQN (DDQN), trained for about 700-800 episodes. The updated code can also be found [here](https://github.com/hridayns/Reinforcement-Learning/tree/master/Atari).

No fancy changes like Prioritized Replay Buffer or any secret hyperparameter changes are required. It's usually something simple, like a small problem with the input preprocessing step.