# Each training run for DDQN agent takes 2 days, and still ends up with -13 avg score, but OpenAi baseline DQN needs only an hour to converge to +18?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn, open-ai, deepmind

***Status***:

For a few weeks now, I have been working on a Double DQN agent for the `PongDeterministic-v4` environment, which you can find [here](https://github.com/hridayns/Reinforcement-Learning/tree/master/Atari).

A single training run lasts for about 7-8 million timesteps (about 7000 episodes) and takes me about 2 days, on Google Collab (K80 Tesla GPU and 13 GB RAM). At first, I thought this was normal because I saw a lot of posts talking about how DQNs take a long time to train for Atari games.

***Revelation***:

But then after cloning the OpenAI baselines [repo](https://github.com/openai/baselines), I tried running `python -m baselines.run --alg=deepq --env=PongNoFrameskip-v4`  and this took about 500 episodes and an hour or 2 to converge to a nice score of +18, without breaking a sweat. Now I'm convinced that I'm doing something terribly wrong but I don't know what exactly.

***Investigation***:

After going through the DQN baseline [code](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/deepq) by OpenAI, I was able to note a few differences:

- I use the `PongDeterministic-v4` environment but they use the `PongNoFrameskip-v4` environment
- I thought a larger **replay buffer size** was important, so I struggled (with the memory optimization) to ensure it was set to **70000** but they set it to a mere **10000**, and still got amazing results.
- I am using a normal **Double DQN**, but they seem to be using a **Dueling Double DQN**.

***Results/Conclusion***

I have my doubts about such a huge increase in performance with just these few changes. So I know there is probably something wrong with my existing implementation. Can someone **point me in the right direction**?

Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although what @Jaden said may be true by itself, it does not really serve to answer my question as I have seen after conducting numerous experiments, and finally reaching close to Dueling Network performance using a normal Double DQN (DDQN).

I made the following changes to my code after closely examining the OpenAI baselines code:

- Used `PongFrameskip-v4` instead of `PongDeterministic-v4`
- Used a small replay buffer of size **10000**
- During a `step_update()` or `replay()` call, changed the condition for a  `return` from `buffer_fill_size < learn_start` to `t < learn_start`, where `t` is the current timestep, `buffer_fill_size` is the current size of buffer that has been filled up with experience tuples, and `learn_start` is the number of timesteps to wait before starting to learn from the experience collected.
- Made sure that the `make_atari()` wrapper function is also called on the `env`:

  ```
  ENV_GYM = 'PongFrameskip-v4'
  env = make_atari(ENV_GYM)
  env = wrap_deepmind(env, frame_stack=True, scale=False)
  ```

  These wrappers may be implemented from scratch or can be obtained from the [OpenAI baseline Atari wrappers](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/common/atari_wrappers.py). I personally used the latter since there is no point in reinventing the wheel.

**Conclusion**:

The biggest step that I overlooked, or rather didn't pay much attention to was the input preprocessing. These few changes improved my DDQN from an average score saturation at -13 in almost 5000 episodes to +18 in about 700-800 episodes. That is indeed a huge difference. You can check out my implementation [here](https://github.com/hridayns/Reinforcement-Learning/tree/master/Atari).

Comment: Could you mention specifically what was different between your original input processing and the improved version? Was this about scaling of NN inputs for instance?

Comment: By input processing, I mean the environment chosen (PongFrameskip-v4, instead of PongDeterministic-v4 in this case) and the wrapper methods `make_atari` and `wrap_deepmind`. I did not have the `make_atari` wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

Dueling architectures create bigger differences in the values of actions in the state space. This is because the state-value **V(s)** function is estimated separately from the state-action value **Q(s, a)**. A new quantity, the advantage of an action, can then be defined as **A(s, a) = Q(s, a) - V(s)**.

> The Q function, however, measures the the value
>   of choosing a particular action when in this state. The advantage
>   function subtracts the value of the state from the Q
>   function to obtain a relative measure of the importance of
>   each action.
>
> [Dueling Network Architectures for Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06581.pdf)

---

To better direct you, here are 2 resources that could really help you understand why those differences are important.

[Speeding up DQN on PyTorch: how to solve Pong in 30 minutes](https://medium.com/mlreview/speeding-up-dqn-on-pytorch-solving-pong-in-30-minutes-81a1bd2dff55)

The main points of the blog are:

1. Use a larger batch size and play several steps before updating
2. Play and train in a separate process
3. Use asyncronous cuda transfers

[RL Adventure](https://github.com/higgsfield/RL-Adventure)

This github library has easy to follow jupyter notebooks and links to all of the papers.
It includes:

- DQN
- Double DQN
- Dueling DQN
- Prioritized Experience Replay
- Noise Networks for Exploration
- Distributional RL
- Rainbow (That network that deepmind made that had so many things in it they couldn't find a good name)
- Distributional RL with Quantile Regression
- Hierarchical Deep RL

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you telling me that this sort of performance, even anything close to it, is impossible using a normal DDQN?

Comment: Yep. Its not that a DDQN is a bad architecture. Its great and does what it was intended to do (i.e., prevent maximization bias (see section 6.7 in http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf)). But there exist qualities that an environment can posses which, when taken into consideration, allow a method to perform better within the same amount of computation time as methods which do not consider these qualities.